# Cannot convert value of type 'IndexPath.Type' to expected argument type 'IndexPath'

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I'm trying to use table view and in the func:
`cellForRowAt` I get an error: `Cannot convert value of type 'IndexPath.Type' to expected argument type 'IndexPath'`

my code is:

```
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cellDish:DishTableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cellDish", for: IndexPath) as! DishTableViewCell      
    return cellDish
}
```

Comment: `for: indexPath`.  Use the parameter `indexPath` lowercase `i` instead of the type `IndexPath`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is your IndexPath parameter.

You are using the class and not an instance. The correct way is:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cellDish:DishTableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cellDish", for: indexPath) as! DishTableViewCell      
    return cellDish
}
```